# How to implement listener pattern in swift

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

I am new in swift moved from java. And some implementaion of  dessign patterns confuse me.

For example I have presudo pattern observer (callback) in java code (there is example below). Namely UI passed own listener to Manager class and listen callbacks isConnected and isDisconnected. If a callback is executed UI class shows certain message "isConnected" or "isDisconnected"

```
    public class UI{
        private Manager mManager;
        void createManager(){
            mManager = new Manager(mManagerLister);
        }
        public void showMessage(String aMsg){
            print(aMsg)
        }
        private final IManagerListener mManagerLister = new IManagerListener{
            void isConnected(){
                this.showMessage("isConnected") 
            }
            void isDisconnected(){
                this.showMessage("isConnected")
            }
        }
    }

    public class Manager{
        interface IManagerListener{
            void isConnected();
            void isDisconnected();
        }
        private final mListener; 
        public Manager(IManagerListener aListener){
            mListener = aListener;
        }
    }
```

How to correctly port this java code to swift code? I tries to port but error message ***Value of type 'UI' has no member 'showMessage'*** is shown

```
  public class UI{
    var manager: Manager?
    var managerListener: IManagerListener?
    func createManager(){
        managerListener = ManagerListenerImp(self)  
        manager = Manager(managerListener)
    }
    public func showMessage(msg: String){
        print(msg)
    }
    class ManagerListenerImp: IManagerListener{
        weak var parent: UI 
        init(parent : UI ){
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func isConnected(){
            parent.showMessage("isConnected") 
            // Value of type 'UI' has no member 'showMessage'
            }
        ..........
    } 
}
```

Perhaps exists more gracefully a way to use callbacks and my way is not correctly?

Comment: Something doesn't seem right with your code, `parent` should be optional if it's `weak`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve it.

1. Delegate Pattern (Using Protocols which are nothing but interfaces
   in Java)
2. Using Blocks/Closures
3. Using KVO

Because you have used interfaces am elaborating on Delegate pattern below.

Modify your code as below

**Declare a protocol**

```
@objc protocol ManagerListenerImp {
    func isConnected()
}
```

**Declare a variable in Manager class**

```
class Manager {
    weak var delegate : ManagerListenerImp? = nil
}
```

**Confirm to `ManagerListenerImp` in your UI class**

```
extension UI : ManagerListenerImp {
    func isConnected () {
        //your isConnected implementation here
    }
}
```

**Pass UI instance (self in swift and this in JAVA to manager class)**

```
func createManager(){
    manager = Manager()
    manager?.delegate = self
}
```

Finally, whenever you wanna trigger `isConnected` from `Manager` class simply say

```
self.delegate?.isConnected()
```

in your Manager class

Hope it helps

Comment: You solution doesn't approach to me. Because after I wiil do  *extension UI: ManagerListenerImp* the UI.isConnected method can be accessilable in any place of code in project, even outter of UI class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by which class has a reference to which, but that shouldn't be too hard to change in the following example.

You might be looking for an Observer Pattern. This can have multiple objects listening to the same changes:

### 1. ManagerStateListener Protocol

Protocol to be implemented by any class that should react to changes to the state of the Manager

```swift
protocol ManagerStateListener: AnyObject {
    func stateChanged(to state: Manager.State)
}
```

### 2. Manager Class

The Manager class contains:

1. Its state
2. A list with listeners
3. Methods for adding, removing and invoking the listeners
4. An example class that implements the ManagerStateListener protocol

```swift
class Manager {
    
    /// The possible states of the Manager
    enum State {
        case one
        case two
        case three
    }
    
    /// The variable that stores the current state of the manager
    private var _currentState: State = .one
    var currentState: State {
        get {
            return _currentState
        }
        set {
            _currentState = newValue
            
            /// Calls the function that will alert all listeners
            /// that the state has changed
            invoke()
        }
    }
    
    /// The list with all listeners
    var listeners: [ManagerStateListener] = []
    
    /// A specific listener that gets initialised here
    let someListener = SomeListener()
    
    init() {
        addListener(someListener) /// Add the listener to the list
    }
    
    /// Method that invokes the stateChanged method on all listeners
    func invoke() {
        for listener in listeners {
            listener.stateChanged(to: currentState)
        }
    }
    
    /// Method for adding a listener to the list of listeners
    func addListener(_ listener: ManagerStateListener) {
        listeners.append(listener)
    }
    
    /// Method for removing a specific listener from the list of listeners
    func removeListener(_ listener: ManagerStateListener) {
        if let index = listeners.firstIndex(where: { $0 === listener }) {
            listeners.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

### 3. SomeListener Class

An example listener that implements the ManagerStateListener protocol, held by the Manager class

```swift
class SomeListener : ManagerStateListener {
    
    func stateChanged(to state: Manager.State) {
        /// Do something based on the newly received state
        switch state {
            case .one:
                print("State changed to one")
            case .two:
                print("State changed to two")
            case .three:
                print("State changed to three")
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is of any help.